# Select a login module programmatically in JBoss AS

Tags: java, authentication, jboss, jboss7.x

I am working on a web application, hosted on a JBoss AS 7.1.1, which will be used by users from two different companies.

In order to authenticate, besides username and password, users must provide the company they belong to.
And, according to the company, the authentication will be against a database or against an Active Directory server.

I have a [`LdapExtLoginModule`](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/LdapExtLoginModule) to authenticate against the Active Directory server:

```
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required" >
    <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url">ldap://ldaphost:389</module-option>
    <module-option name="bindDN">searchuser</module-option>
    <module-option name="bindCredential">password</module-option>
    <module-option name="baseCtxDN">CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com</module-option>
    <module-option name="baseFilter">(sAMAccountName={0})</module-option>
    <module-option name="rolesCtxDN">CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com</module-option>
    <module-option name="roleFilter">(member={1})</module-option>
    <module-option name="roleAttributeID">CN</module-option>
    <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN">false</module-option>
    <module-option name="roleRecursion">2</module-option>
    <module-option name="searchScope">ONELEVEL_SCOPE</module-option>
    <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option>
</login-module>
```

And a [`DatabaseServerLoginModule`](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabaseServerLoginModule) to authenticate against the database:

```
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
    <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
    <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/my-ds"/>
    <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?"/>
    <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT DISTINCT role_id, 'Roles' FROM roles WHERE username = ?"/>
</login-module>
```

According to the company the user provided, how can I manage the authentication and select the properly login module?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: I also asked the same question on JBoss Community's forum: https://community.jboss.org/message/884512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see more possible ways:

- you can configure both login modules in one domain with **`flag=sufficient`**. The second login module will be used as a fallback when the first fail. Then you don't need the company name provided during login;
- as Darran already replied on [JBoss forum](https://community.jboss.org/message/884529#884529), you can implement **your own login module**. You should think how to get the company name in the login module:

  - read the company field value request object

    `(HttpServletRequest) PolicyContext.getContext("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest")`
  - put company and username together and use standard callbacks provided for password-based authentication mechanisms to read username and password. So your username could look for instance like "company#user"

    If the authentication type is FORM, then it's simple to have 3 fields on the login form - `company`, `j_username`, `j_password` and before submitting the form use JavaScript to prefix the submitted `j_username` field with content of the `company` field.